# How to match when JSON in a list?

Tags: elasticsearch

Some guys mapping data like this,

```
"item":[
        {"name":      "ABC" }
        {"brand":     "edf" },
        {"quantity":    12  }
       ]
```

I tried to filter like this :

```
"filter":
     {"term": {"item.brand": "edf}}
```

Then I got this result:

```
    "hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 0,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
```

I recognize that `name`, `brand` and `quantity` are putted in a `[]`

Main question: can we filter it without changing the way we mapping ?

---

#actual case:

```
"item": {
   "categories": [
                     {"deleted_at": null,
                      "description": {
                         "en": "Bun ",
                         "vi": "Bánh Bao "
                                     }
                      },
               ....
                  ]
        }
```

---

My query:

```
["filter":
{"nested": {"path":"item.categories",
        "query":{
                 "term":{"item.categories.description.en":"Bun "}
                }
       }
 }
 ]
```

Got this error:

```
"failed to create query: [nested] nested object under path [item.categories] is not of nested type",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that `item` is of nested type and if that's the case, you need to query with a `nested` query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "item",
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "item.brand": "edf"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

According to the error you get, `item.categories` is not nested, so your initial query was right. However, you should use `match` instead of `term`, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "item.categories.description.en": "Bun"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, it did not work. Would you mind check up my code again. Thanks